# Is it safe to look into fiber optic cables?

Tags: fiber, optical-cable

I have always been told the it is highly unsafe to stare into fiber optic cables, but have also seen articles saying that this is a myth. For example, [this one](https://www.ecmag.com/section/systems/myths-fiber-optics).

So it is safe to look into fiber optic cables, or not?

Comment: What one considers safe is not by definition what someone else considers safe. Given that fibre optics that are used for distances less than 100 meter are not laser powered, and you obviously are talking about this kind, they could not be damaging, but someone who is sensitive to light could still get some damage. For example, it could trigger a migraine.

Comment: Its going to completely depend on the type and amount of light being transmitted through the cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this safety Article.

[Working with Fiber Optic Cable](https://www.networkcablinglosangeles.com/top-10-safety-rules-fiber-optics/)

> Wear safety glasses. – Every person in the area must wear safety
> glasses with side shields to prevent fiber shards and splinters from
> entering the eyes. ...
>
> Wear protective aprons. ...
>
> **Avoid fiber ends.** ...
>
> Contact lens wearers. ...
>
> Keep hands away from face. ...
>
> Well-ventilated area. ...
>
> No combustible materials. ...
>
> Dispose of scraps.

You should keep away from the ends of the cable and make sure that they are properly terminated.

Also see this article which relates to use and handling of fiber optic cable:

[Looking into a fiber optic cable](https://www.cablinginstall.com/cable/article/16467818/use-caution-when-working-with-fiber)

> Since optical fiber carries light, it is assumed to be the safer
> medium. This belief may be misplaced, however. While optical fiber
> doesn`t carry electricity, it does transmit light, which, in some
> instances, can damage the eye

While it might depend on the light level (you cannot tell except with measuring equipment) , I do not recommend looking into the end of the cable and would certainly not do that myself.

Comment: This seems to primarily talk about firbe optics before installation, and the kind that a laser will shine through. Networking with fibre optics (cables smaller than 100m) are usually already terminated and only LED power them, they are not the same.

Comment: I use the article to suggest staying away from looking into it. I do not recommend looking into the cable end. Thanks. - I amended my answer for this.